# Cannot compile boost program with Codelite

Tags: c++, boost, ide, codelite

I have a program which is utilizing the boost library, however when I try building my code with Codelite I am getting the following errors:

```
/bin/sh -c '/usr/bin/make -j4 -e -f  Makefile'
----------Building project:[ SecureObjectStoreServer - Debug ]----------
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dizzy/Programming/C++/SecureObjectStore/SecureObjectStoreServer'
/usr/bin/g++-5 -o ./Debug/SecureObjectStoreServer @"SecureObjectStoreServer.txt" -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/  -L.
./Debug/main.cpp.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
```

I checked to find the location of the boost library needed and found that the path is **/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so**

I then tried to add this within the build settings in Codelite so that I can properly compile the program.
The menu is **settings->build settings->Compilers tab.**

Then I select the **Advanced tab** and enter the following values under the **Global Paths** section:
**Include Path: /usr/include/boost/**

**Libraries Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/**

I did not change anything else in settings.

However, it does not seem to fix this issue.

I am able to properly compile boost programs via command line using gcc and adding the -lboost_system flag.  This works fine so the issue really is configuring Codelite to do this.

I searched online for help on this but I did not find anything that fixes my issue.

I am running Codelite v.9.1.0. on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial)

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures, post the relevant information as text in the question itself instead.

Comment: I removed the links and added better information in text.

Comment: You still haven't posted the actual error.